# Laravel 8 Class League AwsS3Adapter not found in FilesystemManager

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

- Laravel Version: 8.12
- PHP Version: 7.4.16
- Database Driver & Version: PostgreSQL 12

#### Description:

When trying to use the Storage class to list a directory with the code below:

```
$directories = Storage::disk('s3')->allDirectories("/");
```

I got the following error:

```
Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found
```

I checked the files in the vendor folder and they are all there. I'm using version 1.0 of league / flysystem-aws-s3-v3 as you can see below in my composer require.

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "^1.1",
    "paquettg/php-html-parser": "^3.1",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
}
```

I am without direction of what may be wrong, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Can you secure that the flysystem-aws-s3-v3 is installed in the lock file of composer?

Comment: Yes I already ran the composer dump-autoload

Comment: I checked and it's on composer.lock